# CGAL: How to merge two (coplanar) polyhedron facets with more than one common edge?

Tags: cgal

With CGAL, Using any kernal, but preferably the Epeck, how can I safely merge two coplanar facets (of any degree) of a Polyhedron_3? Both facets are on the *same* Polyhedron_3 surface and already sharing one or more edges. The desired result is that the common edges are all removed, the two facets become a single facet, and no antennae or unconnected vertices remain after the operation. As an example, I would like to merge facets F1 and F2 shown in the diagram below, and have the edges denoted by HE1, HE2 and HE3 removed.

[image: merge example diagram]

I want to achieve the same result as CGAL's [`join_facet`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedron__3.html#a4f3e7c4e0800462026443a7ad0ca6db8), except that (I believe) `join_facet` is only useful for joining facets which only have a single common edge. If there are more, `join_facet` may create antennae, which causes subsequent operations on the polyhedron to fail.

Calculating whether the facets are coplanar is not part of the question, I can handle this myself.

The ultimate aim is to merge all facets of a triangulated polyhedron which are coplanar. I am assuming the best way to do this is to iteratively merge touching coplanar facets of the polyhedron. I will therefore also accept answers which explain alternative means to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function [`join_loop`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedron__3.html#ad5a29fe94196629193da3c95e5eba5e9) if your facets have the number of edges.

Comment: The help for `join_loop` states that "Both facets and the vertices along the facet denoted by g gets removed". I assumed this meant there would be a hole after this operation if they're touching. The diagram also implies this is for joining two unconnected facets. Could you possibly provide a small example of its use in this context?

Comment: If you have two tetrahedra having one facet coplanar with each other, this will allow to remove it and the polyhedron will then bound only one volume.

Comment: I've now clarified the question, I don't want to merge two facets of different polyhedra, I want to merge two facets of the *same* polyhedron, like you would with `join_facet`, except that `join_facet` is only useful for joining facets which only have a single common edge. If there are more, `join_facet` may create antennae. The ultimate aim is to merge all facets of a triangulated polyhedron which are coplanar.

Comment: No `join_facet` is working even if you have n edges, and it is working on only one Polyhedron (in my example the two tetrahedra was in the same Polyhedron)

Comment: ok (thought a tetrahedron was a 3D shape, so didn't see how two can be part of a polyhedral surface, actually I still don't fully understand, but it doesn't matter). Anyway, are you saying that `join_facet` will delete the incident facet, and remove *all* the edges which were previously the border between those facets, leaving no antennae? The help is not clear on this.

Comment: This is exactly what the documentation is saying (there is a link in my answer)

Comment: Your answer has a link to `join_loop` (I thought we were now talking about `join_facet`). If you mean, `join_loop` it states that the precondition is *"The facets denoted by h and g are different and have equal degree (i.e., number of edges)."*, so surely this will not work in my case as the two facets may have different numbers of edges (e.g. a joining a triangle and a quad). If you mean `join_facet`, the help does not state what happens to other common edges just that the opposite facet is *"removed"* (at least not in the help where I now link to in my question).

Comment: Sorry I meant `join_loop`.  You need to split the edges then to have perfect matching.

Comment: I've looked carefully at the help for `join_loop`, and I still don't understand how to apply it to my case. Exactly which halfedge handle would be passed in as `h` and which passed in as `g`? A basic example would clear it up the confusion easily.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you want to do. It is a bit tricky to do. I do have some code doing it in a project. Check [the function join_faces_with_same_color](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-voronoi-cropping/source/browse/Voronoi_cropping_2/include/voronoi_cropping.h).