# CGAL: Join coplanar Polyhedron facets

Tags: cgal

This topic is not new, but I couldn't find any satisfying solutions. I have a valid Polyhedron which consists of pure triangles and is not closed. Now I would like to merge coplanar facets resulting in a single Polyhedron facet with as many vertices as necessary.

I wrote a function iterating over all edges and using join_facet() in case the corresponding edge is non-border and the opposite facet is coplanar. This works on simple meshes, but fails on more complicated ones.

If you take a look at the picture, you can see how facets are joined (red) which do not even share a halfedge and furthermore are not coplanar at all. I can not explain this, since the first thing I'm checking is if facets of halfedge and halfedge->opposite() are coplanar.

[image]

A second problem is if I'm ending up joining coplanar Polyhedron facets with several common halfedges. The problem is already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231611/cgal-how-to-merge-two-coplanar-polyhedron-facets-with-more-than-one-common-ed). But it is still not clear what join_facet() does in this case. Will the other halfedges still exist? This is no problem since I'm iterating over them anyway (would be more of a problem if they do not exist anymore since my Edge_iterator still wants to iterate over them). But how do I get rid of them?

This is my code:

```
void mergeCoplanarFacets(Polyhedron *P_out) const {
  for (Polyhedron::Edge_iterator j = P_out->edges_begin(); j != P_out->edges_end(); ++j) {
    Polyhedron::Edge_iterator i = j; // copy necessary for iterator to work after removing halfedges
    if(i->is_border_edge()) { // if halfedge is border, there is no neighbor facet
      std::cout << "Border is edge" << std::endl;
      continue;
    }
    // check normals
    if(coplanar(i, i->opposite())) {
      std::cout << "Coplanar facet found" << std::endl;
      if(CGAL::circulator_size(i->opposite()->vertex_begin()) >= 3 && CGAL::circulator_size(i->vertex_begin()) >= 3) {
        std::cout << "Join facet " << i->facet()->id() << " with " << i->opposite()->facet()->id() << std::endl;
        P_out->join_facet(i);
      }
      else
        std::cerr << "Faces could not be joined" << std::endl;
    }
  }
```

```
bool MeshModel::coplanar(const Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle &h1, const Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle &h2) const {
  // check coplanarity of at least three points from the new triangle
  if (CGAL::coplanar(h1->vertex()->point(), h1->next()->vertex()->point(), h1->next()->next()->vertex()->point(), h2->vertex()->point())
      && CGAL::coplanar(h1->vertex()->point(), h1->next()->vertex()->point(), h1->next()->next()->vertex()->point(), h2->next()->vertex()->point())
      && CGAL::coplanar(h1->vertex()->point(), h1->next()->vertex()->point(), h1->next()->next()->vertex()->point(), h2->next()->next()->vertex()->point()))
        return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Any other solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: halfedge and halfege->opposite() are always coplanar, they share the two same points and form the edge. Did you mean halfedge->face() and halfedge()->opposite()->face() ?

Comment: Was just a wrong formulation. In the code I'm actually taking the corresponding facets.

Answer (score 0):

Iteratively joining faces might lead to issues as soon as the topology of the set of coplanar faces is not that of a disk.
My advice for such a task, is to identify all the coplanar patches. For each such patch if it is not a topological disk, then triangulate it using a constrained triangulation. If it is a topological disk, you can keep it like this or retriangulate it too. Note that you might want to add an extra step on the boundary of your patch to discard vertices of "degree 2" that are collinear with its neighbors.

I have some code doing it, I'll see what we can do to release it publicly.

Comment: What is a „topological disk“? I‘m not sure how triangulation would help here since I would like to end up joining the triangles and not making triangles. In my example the whole wall consisting of several triangles should end up in a Polyhedron with 4 vertices.

Comment: Think of a cube that has in the middle of one face another smaller cube. That face has 2 boundary cycle of halfedges that you cannot simply join (otherwise the interior square will be disconnected). The triangulation is here to help to keep it connected.

Comment: But since these are boundary halfedges to non-coplanar facets, I would not even try to join them. In your case I should end up with a „squared“ ring. I’m assuming there are no facets between these two cubes if they are connected.

Comment: Sure but then you somehow have a hole in the face and this is no longer valid. The HDS is probably fine with this but Polyhedron is not.

Comment: So I assume there is no solution to this problem? If the coplanar joined facet would be a facet with a hole, also triangulation would not change this. (I really want every neighboring coplanar facet ending up in a single facet.)

Comment: This will be possible only is it is a topological disk otherwise you need another data structure.